# ToolBar Android

Tags: java, android

[image]

Pessoal, eu queria poder tirar <- a seta de voltar do ToolBar. Alguém poderia me dizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover a seta da `Toolbar`, basta adicionar essa linha de código no `onCreate()` da sua `Activity`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Adicione após ter setado a `Toolbar` como `ActionBar`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz, funcionou!

Comment: De nada, feliz por ajudar. Não esqueça de marcar como resposta certa! ;)